# How to make fennec(firefox) not reopen and automatically load the last open tab?

Tags: firefox-for-android

After removing the Firefox Android browser (Fennec) activity and reopening it again, the lastly open tab appears and loads the webpage.

How can *this* be disabled?
*(by this, I mean that the tab that was last opened, is **reloaded automatically** upon reopening the firefox activity.)*

**background**

1. I **do** want open tabs to be conserved during cycles of closing and reopening the firefox/fennec activity.
2. However, it is annoying that this setting to keep tabs, provokes the last open tab (which was displayed at the moment the firefox activity was closed) to be automatically reloaded. More often then not I do not want to revisit this exact webpage, but was expansive mobile data volume and time for this.

Comment: Was Firefox just in background or did you explicitly close the Firefox app (e.g. by swiping it away form the recents list)?

Comment: explicitly closed

Comment: What page do you want to load when you open Firefox with multiple tabs open?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio upon reopening Firefox and to avoid loading any online resource (while keeping the tabs) it would be most lovely that it drops you onto a "new tab page". Indeed this is some workaround currently, as this way upon reopening you are at the offline new tab page (hence no load).

Comment: Did you have a look at the edit made on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

To disable restorng tabs, go to Firefox settings, then Advanced, click on Restore tabs. Select "Don't restore after quitting Firefox". It will not open previous tabs when you restart the browser.

But you said that is not the behavior you are looking for. Then the other possibility is to set as homepage a page you don't care for.  Go to Settings -> General -> Home -> Set a homepage, then select Custom and enter: `about:blank` (a blank page as your homepage). Click OK. Enable "Also use for new tabs".

From now, before closing Firefox, open a new tab. A blank page will be displayed. When you open the browser again, the blank page will be loaded. The other tabs will still be there.

Comment: This does not keep the tabs. As expressed in the question, I do not want to delete all tabs, I only want to prevent the last active browser tab to be loading upon reopening firefox. With your suggestion, as tested, the tab is indeed not loaded, at the costs of loosing all tabs as well.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace See edit